# What is the possbile reasons for a record in AccountShare Object disappeared suddenly?

Tags: apex, visualforce, data, object, accountshare

Just found some records in my AccountShare Object disappeared suddenly.

All related objects(Accounts,group,etc),batchs and tables are checked and nothings has changed.

row casue remained unchanged too.
And no signal for manual overwrites as well.

Are there any othre factors that i may missed out?

Comment: Has the owner of any of those Accounts been updated?